# Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' is most specific for these arguments:

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, user-controls

I have a usercontrol with a repeater. Originally in page load I had code which grabbed data from the database and bound to the repeater. I now want to take this functionality outside of the usercontrol so that I can have more than one on the page and have them bind to different data.

My code now is:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class UpdateList
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

    Private m_dataSource As Object

    <TypeConverter("System.Windows.Forms.Design.DataSourceConverter, System.Design")> _
    <Category("Data")> _
    <DefaultValue(Nothing)> _
    Public Property DataSource() As Object
        Get
            Return Me.m_dataSource
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            If Me.m_dataSource <> value Then
                m_dataSource = value
                tryDataBinding()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property UpdateCount As Integer
        Get
            Return m_UpdateCount
        End Get
    End Property


    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


    End Sub

    Protected Sub tryDataBinding()

        rep_Updates.DataSource = Me.m_dataSource
        rep_Updates.DataBind()

    End Sub

End Class
```

I get a wavy line at `<DefaultValue(Nothing)>` and get an error:

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' is most specific for these arguments:
>
> 'Public Sub New(value As Boolean)': Not most specific.
>
> 'Public Sub New(value As Byte)': Not most specific.
>
> 'Public Sub New(value As Char)': Not most specific.

What does this mean? Thanks

**UPDATE**

The fix was to change the property declaration for datasource to...

```
    Private m_dataSource As Object

    Public Property DataSource() As Object
        Get
            Return Me.m_dataSource
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            m_dataSource = value
            tryDataBinding()
        End Set
    End Property
```

Comment: **at least in WinForms** the DefaultValue attribute ctor cant be Nothing. Since it doesnt define an intitial starting value, but a comparison value for when to persist the property value - which seems subious anyway in this case, just remove the attribute.

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks... I got the snippet as c# - just converted and pasted it into my code not spotting System.Windows.Forms... Removing TypeConverter, Category and DefaultValue did the trick. Post as answer and I will mark.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I write \[DefaultValue(null)\] in VB.NET? <DefaultValue(Nothing)> does not compile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29748703/how-do-i-write-defaultvaluenull-in-vb-net-defaultvaluenothing-does-not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**at least in WinForms** the DefaultValue attribute ctor cant be `Nothing` (there is no such definition in Object Browser). `DefaultAttribute` doesnt define an initial starting value (in spite of the name), but the comparison value for when to persist a property value.  This seems dubious anyway in the case of a webform and datasource, so just remove the attribute.

As you noted the `TypeConverter` is probably out of place as well.

Comment: I believe this is factually wrong. `DefaultValueAttribute` does have at least one [fitting constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cx2at1a8.aspx) where a null reference could be passed; the problem is that VB.NET's `Nothing` does not just mean "the null reference", it also means "default value" for the parameter type and therefore matches every single constructor overload; the compiler doesn't know which one to pick. [See my answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29748327/240733)

Comment: No, it is not factually incorrect.  `Boolean`, `Byte`, `Char` etc are Types.  `Nothing` is not a Type, and there is no overload for it.  You are correct that part of the issue is that in VB `Nothing` <> `null`.  Your new answer using `DirectCast` is clever and worthwhile, but it is in fact *converting* Nothing to a Type so it fits one of the ctors.

Comment: Of course `Nothing` is not a type. That's not the point. Your answer is factually wrong because you claim that _"the `DefaultAttribute` ctor cant be nothing (there is no such definition in Object Browser)"_. Unless I misunderstand your (somewhat imprecise) wording, this is clearly wrong: There *is* a ctor overload that accepts a value of type `object`; such as the null reference; a.k.a. `Nothing`. If you wrote the same code in C#, you'd see that your statement cannot be right: `[DefaultValue(null)]` is perfectly valid C# code.

Comment: (Btw.: There is only one version of the `DefaultValueAttribute` class, and that isn't specific to Windows Forms. So if you make some statement about the constructors that `DefaultValueAttribute` has or doesn't have, then that statement is valid for Windows Forms, but also for any other code that uses this custom attribute class.)