# How do I write [DefaultValue(null)] in VB.NET? <DefaultValue(Nothing)> does not compile

Tags: c#, vb.net, overload-resolution, c#-to-vb.net

This isn't as trivial as it appears to be. It's a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23266178/240733).

Let's say I have a Windows Forms user control with a property:

```cs
// using System.ComponentModel;

[DefaultValue(null)]
public object DataSource { … }
```

If I translate this to VB.NET, I would try this:

```vb
'Imports System.ComponentModel

<DefaultValue(Nothing)>
Public Property DataSource As Object
    …
End Property
```

This won't work because the compiler has problems choosing the correct [overload of `DefaultValueAttribute`'s constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute.DefaultValueAttribute.aspx):

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible `New` is most specific for these arguments:
>
> - `Public Sub New(value As Boolean)`: Not most specific.
> - `Public Sub New(value As Byte)`: Not most specific.
> - `Public Sub New(value As Char)`: Not most specific.

I am quite certain this is because `Nothing` in VB.NET not only means "the null reference" (`null` in C#), but also "the default value for" the parameter type (`default(T)` in C#). Because of this ambiguity, every constructor overload is a potential match.

`<DefaultValue(CObj(Nothing))>` also won't work because it is not a constant value.

How exactly *do* I write this in VB.NET?

**P.S.:** `<DefaultValue(GetType(Object), Nothing)>` is an option, but it circumvents the problem. I'm really interested if there's any way to use the same constructor for `DefaultValueAttribute` as the C# version does.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> "[…] won't work because the compiler has problems choosing the correct overload of `DefaultValueAttribute`'s constructor[.]"

The compiler can be assisted with a type-cast of `Nothing` to the desired type:

```vb
<DefaultValue(DirectCast(Nothing, Object))>
```

> "`<DefaultValue(CObj(Nothing))>` also won't work because it is not a constant value."

Fortunately, unlike `CObj(Nothing)`, the compiler considers `DirectCast(Nothing, Object)` — and suprisingly, `CType(Nothing, Object)`, too — a constant value, so it is accepted.

Comment: @Stack if you want to have the same code as C#, you have to cast to String :-) See http://goo.gl/iP3N7e `.custom instance void [System]System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute::.ctor(string)`

Comment: Casting to string also has the benefit that ReSharper doesn't get confused. With `DirectCast(Nothing, Object)`, it thinks it's ambiguous even though the compiler doesn't.

Comment: Amazing how something so simple keeps getting weirder and weirder. :-D

Comment: 'CType(Nothing, Object)' also works - which is really strange since 'CObj(Nothing)' is just an shorthand syntax for the CType version.